# Programmer Day. Do you celebrate it?

Tags: discussion

Do you honor [Programmers' Day](http://programmerday.info/FAQ.html), the 256-th day of the year?

It'll fall on 13 September this year, being a non-leaping one and all that jazz.

Comment: belongs on meta.

Comment: No, this really doesn't belong on meta, either.  This isn't about S[F|O|U].

Comment: Should we not also celebrate the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th, etc, etc days of the year? How about the 131,072nd day of each millennium? :-)

Comment: This day is now official in Russia: http://news.slashdot.org/story/09/09/12/1548245/Russias-New-Official-Holiday-mdash-Programmers-Day. In xUSSR many professions have a dedicated day.

Answer (score 6):

No. I use a 0-based index for my days, so I celebrate Day 255.

Comment: Day 255 is still the 256th day in your 0-indexed calendar.  Unless you think an array containing only an element at index 0 has no elements in it.

Comment: @Wobble: Thanks for explaining the joke.  I don't know what we'd do without you.  Perhaps in your next comment you can explain the humor behind the chicken that crossed the road?

Answer (score 4):

Programmers day only exists one time in history: October 10th, 2010.  Or in binary form 101010.  It's quite simply the ultimate answer.

Comment: "In history"? Surely 10101010 existed ...

Comment: Why not 010101?

Comment: *Sigh* @ people who just saw that it was binary and didn't convert to decimal. :)

Answer (score 3):

I celebrate programmer's day nearly every day of the year.

Answer (score 2):

What about October 10? (10/10 - binary day)

Comment: Next year, binary day is going to *rock*!

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, day 256 is this Sunday: September 13th. I think we should celebrate on both Sept 13th and October 10, though. Why miss a chance to party?

Edit: of course, as I say this random edits the original question so it now includes the Sept 13th date. Sheesh.